# Load data from a database in Python

Tags: python, database, adodb

I'm new to python and I'm trying to load data from a database. The code runs without error but does not output anything even though I ask it to print in 3 places (as a check that it's working). 
It's probably something simple but I can't see the problem - I'd be very grateful for any pointers. Thanks!

Here's the code (it is correctly indented but this site has ignored it):

```
import win32com.client
from numpy import array,isnan,delete,arange

class LoadData:
    db = ""
    def __init__(self):
        self.db='330_26112015.mdb'
        print db                                    # Doesn't seem to print this
        [self.EventCode, self.Easting, self.Northing]=import_db(self,self.db[0])

    def import_db(self,file):
        print self.db                               # Doesn't seem to print this
        connection = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
        DSN = 'PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE='+file+';'
        connection.Open(DSN)
        recordset = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')

        Name =('Stb Maggy')
        recordset.Open('SELECT VesselID FROM SurveyEventData WHERE VesselName=?', Name, connection)
        ID = recordset.GetRows()
        print "ID is:", ID                          # Doesn't seem to print this

        recordset.Open('SELECT EventCode, Easting, Northing FROM SurveyEventData Where VesselID=?', ID, connection)
        D = recordset.GetRows()

        EventCode = array(D[0])
        Easting = array(D[1])
        Northing = array(D[2])

        return EventCode, Easting, Northing
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this? Maybe you should try defining a main at the end (Outside the class and at root indentation)

```
def main():
   obj = LoadData()
   obj.import_db('somefile')
```

Comment: Thanks :) I edited the code so that it would reach the second function - it was an issue with 'self'. Now for the real issue: I have tried many methods for connecting to MS Access databases (.mdb) & coming against errors, now I'm trying pyodbc:                                                                                               cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;PORT=1433;DATABASE='+file+';UID= ;PWD= ')            this is the same as described in many tutorials but the error: SQL Server does not exist or access denied is displayed. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Might be a firewall issue. Stating the obvious, either the server might not be up or not visible to the IDE you're running your code from

Answer (score 0):

Your second and third print statements look okay, which seems to indicate that your code doesn't reach them. The problem is in your `__init__()` method. Here's a fix:

```
class LoadData:
    db = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.db='330_26112015.mdb'
        print self.db
        [self.EventCode, self.Easting, self.Northing] = self.import_db(self.db)
```

The problems with your version were:

1. confusion between local variables and instance variables (printing `db` instead of `self.db`), and similarly between functions in the local namespace vs. instance methods (calling `import_db()` instead of `self.import_db()`).
2. confusion about `self` and its use. Instance methods (like your `import_db()`) automatically get the instance as the first argument, so you don't have to pass it in. In fact, calling `self.import_db(self, self.db)` should give you an error telling you that `import_db` got three arguments when it was expecting two (since the instance is automatically added to the start of the argument list).
3. String and list. The variable `self.db` is a string, so referencing `self.db[0]` is the string `"3"`, and not the name of your database file (which is what I assume you intended).
4. Initializing to an empty string. This is more stylistic than ironclad, but it's better to use `None` rather than an empty string to indicate that a variable hasn't yet been assigned; it's easier to test and less error-prone.